# Calculating energy consumed from lateral movement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy

---

## **Question:**

How do I calculate the Joules consumed by a car starting at zero, cruising at 88.5 km/h and then coming to a stop. Total distance traveled of 485 km. Losses due to drag, friction and heat are ignored.

---

## **Background Information:**

It seems like one should be able to get a very rough estimate of efficiency by comparing the PE of the battery (for Tesla 70D: 70kWh==252M Joules) to the output of the car by calculating the Joules expended (for Tesla 70D: range @55MPH=~485Km and mass=~2200Kg) but all my calculations are out of whack (output > input). Can someone explain how I get the output in Joules (input seems simple enough)?

I was using this as a reference: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/7-2-kinetic-energy-and-the-work-energy-theorem/

Additional parameters to consider: Initial velocity ($t_0$) is zero. We reach cruising speed of 88.5kMh (55MPH) at $t_1$ and remain at that speed until $t_2$ at which time we decelerate to zero at $t_3$.

I do not own this car and this is NOT homework! I am genuinely curious if this is a good technique to get a VERY rough estimate of system efficiency.

Comment: Depends how you define efficiency. In the end, if you drive in a circle all energy is lost, so efficiency is 0. So the only question seems where you put the threshold for what counts as "loss" and what doesn't.

Comment: How do you get the Joules expended from just the mass of the car and the range?

Comment: Also I don't think 2.2 kg is right

Comment: You are correct. It should be 2200 Kg. Work is done by moving a mass over distance so I just need to figure out how much energy was expended doing so. I am also assuming the 485Km is in a straight line perpendicular to center of gravity (no change in height). Or you can think of it as finding the max possible efficiency given the parameters.

Comment: Well, in that case it should work in principle without using any energy (if you have enough time). All else is just engineering ;)

Comment: Oops, yes forgot to mention the car starts at zero goes up to 88.5 kMh (55MPH) and then back to zero but that does bring up a point that if the velocity were constant (no acceleration) and we assume no wind, friction or heat loss, then the energy consumed would be zero... hmmm... So I think the difference in input to output energy (during the time when acceleration was zero) would be an indirect measurement of that energy lost to wind, friction and heat... Useful but I am still at a loss as to my mundane task of converting the output energy to Joules. Any help?

Comment: At 88 km/h it is mostly aerodynamic drag that consumes the energy, the rolling friction and motor inefficiency will contribute a bit. Computing all of these are tough engineering problems. One can expect 10-20 kW to keep the car running (accurate numbers should be shown by the car computer). And this knowledge easily gives the range.